# Emacs on Android - org-mode - error - `(wrong-type-argument stringp (require . t-mouse))`

Tags: org-mode, mouse, android

I'm running Emacs in Android under ZShaolin, with whatever the default configuration is.  When I open an org-mode file (or try to enable org-mode), I get an error:

```
(wrong-type-argument stringp (require . t-mouse))
```

[This seems to be the case whether or not I enable the trackpad (I'm running on a tablet with keyboard)]

Here is the backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp (require . t-mouse))
  string-match("\\(\\`\\|/\\)org-exp\\(\\.elc\\|\\.el\\)?\\(\\.gz\\)?\\'" (require . t-mouse))
  load-history-filename-element("\\(\\`\\|/\\)org-exp\\(\\.elc\\|\\.el\\)?\\(\\.gz\\)?\\'")
  eval-after-load("org-exp" (add-hook (quote org-export-preprocess-before-normalizing-links-hook) (quote org-remove-file-link-modifiers)))
  org-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(org-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer Notes.org> "/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u139630781/scratch/Org/Notes.org" nil nil "/storage/emulated/legacy/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u139630781/scratch/Org/Notes.org" ((16419 . 51200) 20))
  find-file-noselect("/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u139630781/scratch/Org/Notes.org" nil nil t)
  find-file("/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u139630781/scratch/Org/Notes.org" t)
  call-interactively(find-file nil nil)
```

Comment: Please do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, trigger the error, and add the backtrace to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your Emacs has a malformed `load-history` variable. Its documentation states:

> **Documentation:**
>   Alist mapping loaded file names to symbols and features.
>   Each alist element should be a list `(FILE-NAME ENTRIES...)`, where
>   `FILE-NAME` is the name of a file that has been loaded into Emacs.
>   The file name is absolute and true (i.e. it doesn't contain symlinks).
>   As an exception, one of the alist elements may have `FILE-NAME` `nil`,
>   for symbols and features not associated with any file.

In your case `load-history` contains an element whose `car` is not a string but `(require . t-mouse)`. `load-history-filename-element` expects a file name (a string) and bails.

I don't know what the reason is (and cannot find out because I don't have an Android device) , but we can try to get around this by creating a slightly more robust version of `load-history-filename-element`:

```
(defun load-history-filename-element (file-regexp)
  "Get the first elt of `load-history' whose car matches FILE-REGEXP.
        Return nil if there isn't one."
  (let* ((loads load-history)
         (load-elt (and loads (car loads))))
    (save-match-data
      (while (and loads
                  (or (null (car load-elt))
                      (not (and (stringp (car load-elt)) ; new condition
                                (string-match file-regexp (car load-elt))))))
        (setq loads (cdr loads)
              load-elt (and loads (car loads)))))
    load-elt))
```

For the record, this is the original version (Emacs 24.4.1):

```
(defun load-history-filename-element (file-regexp)
  "Get the first elt of `load-history' whose car matches FILE-REGEXP.
    Return nil if there isn't one."
  (let* ((loads load-history)
         (load-elt (and loads (car loads))))
    (save-match-data
      (while (and loads
                  (or (null (car load-elt))
                      (not (string-match file-regexp (car load-elt)))))
        (setq loads (cdr loads)
              load-elt (and loads (car loads)))))
    load-elt))
```

All of this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  That indeed works.  Now I can meaningfully interact with org-mode files on my tablet (if I edit the file in the dropbox directory, I can have changes propagate back via MobileOrg to my other devices (i.e. desktop computers).)  This is very useful.

Comment: Hmm...actually getting the changes to propogate back to my desktop isn't working quite as I had wanted, but that's beyond the scope of emacs.stackexchange I think.

Answer (score 4):

For the record: I have dug up the root cause for this one. It is not for ZShaolin build, but rather, for Termux build of Emacs, but the source of the broken `load-history` entry is the same, it's an Emacs bug resulting from running undumped, which Android builds necessarily have to do.

See https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/423 for the full story.

The most general solution appears to be commenting out the line `(setq current-load-list nil)` in `/usr/share/emacs/<version>/loadup.el` -- the presence of this line is intended to excise `loadup.el` from `load-history` with emacs that is dumped into a single binary with the lisp components during compilation. On Android, with the requirement that executables must be PIE, a dumped binary will simply not run, so both the ZShaolin and Termux builds of emacs run undumped, and this line results in the creation of a bogus `load-history` entry.

Comment: I'm not even using anything Android, and am here four years later, but this solved my problem enabling python-mode in Emacs 27 emacsformacosx.com build..no clue why I also have non-string car elements in my load-history.

Comment: Saved my life. I'm running Emacs 28 from emacsformacosx.com on Catalina. Thank you sir!